# Discord Py Tasks. Won't Run task

Tags: python, discord.py

I need help with the following code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os

TOKEN = "tokenthing"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$$")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
        test.start()
        print("Succesful Login as {0.user}".format(client))
        


@client.command()
async def GiveMoney(ctx, user : discord.User, value : int):
        if value <= 0:
                await ctx.send("Can't send negative money.")
                return
        else:
                pass
        
        sender = str(ctx.author)
        reciever = str(user)

        if os.path.exists(sender+".txt"):
                pass
        else: 
                await ctx.send("You Don't have an account. Type $$CreateAccount to create one.")
                return

        if os.path.exists(reciever+".txt"):
                pass
        else:
                await ctx.send("The Person you are trying to give money doesn't have a bank Account")
                return

        try:
                f= open(sender+".txt", "r")
                balance = f.read()
                f.close()
                balance = int(balance)
                balance = balance - value
                balance = str(balance)
                f = open(sender+".txt", "w")
                f.write(balance)
                f.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
                await ctx.send("You don't have a Bank account. Type $$CreateAccount to create one.")
                return
        try:
                f = open(reciever+".txt", "r")
                balance = f.read()
                f.close()
                balance = int(balance)
                balance = balance + value
                balance = str(balance)
                f = open(reciever+".txt", "w")
                f.write(balance)
                f.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
                await ctx.send("The Person You are sending money dosen't have an account")
        print("{0} sent {1} to {2}".format(sender, value, reciever))


@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def test(ctx):
        for i in range(10):
                print(i)




client.run(TOKEN)
```

I can't seem for the life of me to get it to run the task on bot readiness.
I'm not getting any error or anything it just seems to skip it.
I am using Discord.py-rewrite on a windows 10 machine.
I suspect I missed something with the commands but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `await` when you start your loop. Because your function is `async`. Example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await test.start()
```